# nginx add_after_body and if

Tags: nginx

Nginx is saying that "add_after_body" isn't allowed in an "if" statement, is there any alternative?
Here is the current config

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^/(home|page1|page2|page4)(.*+)\.html$) {
        add_after_body /stats.html;
}
```

The same problem occurs if I put the if block in a location block instead

Here's the error:

```
Reloading nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "add_after_body" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:22
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Here's the complete server block:

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen   [::]:80; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name .mydoma.in;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root   /var/www;

    gzip             on;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/xml;
    gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_comp_level  4;

    #if ($request_uri ~* ^/(forum|thread|post|announcement|user|calendar|event|top10)(.*+)\.html$) {
    #   add_after_body /stats.html;
    #}

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        #MyBB Config

        rewrite ^/forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forumdisplay.php?fid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost;
        rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2;

        rewrite ^/post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?pid=$1;

        rewrite ^/announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ /announcements.php?aid=$1;

        rewrite ^/user-([0-9]+)\.html$ /member.php?action=profile&uid=$1;

        rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?calendar=$1;
        rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2;
        rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3;
        rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4;
        rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2;

        rewrite ^/event-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1;

        rewrite ^/sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ /misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1;

        #if ($request_uri ~* "^/(forum|thread|post|announcement|user|calendar|event|top10)") {
            #        add_after_body /stats.html;
        #}

    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    #expires 1M;

    # Static assets
    location ~* ^.+\.(manifest|appcache)$ {
        expires -1;
    }

    # Set expires max on static file types
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }

    # opt-in to the future
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";

    location = /50x/ {
        random_index on;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50X/;
}
```

I've tried putting the statement both inside the `location` statement, and outside (`add_after_body` works without an `if` statement both inside a `location` block or `server` block)

Comment: Did you build `nginx` with the *addition* module, as `--with-http_addition_module`? It's required for the `add_after_body` directive, but not included by default. Also, I don't know `nginx` well enough yet to tell, but it may just not be *allowed* in `if` statements - they seem to be restrictive and discouraged.

Comment: Please show exact error message.

Comment: Yes I did build `nginx` with the `http_addition` module, however I can't see any alternative to using an `if` statement other than a lot of `location` statements, which I'd rather not have to write

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. It seems appropriate.

```
location ~ (forumdisplay|showthread|announcements|member|calendar\.php$) {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_pass php;
  add_after_body /stats.html;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because the pages aren't made by me

Comment: I originally tried that but it blocked the processing of other locations because these URI are rewritten later on, using a location stops the rewrite later on, another other solution is to put every rewrite into a location but I'd rather not do that

Comment: I tried something like that but the rewrites won't work if I use another location.